# Fill a column with consecutive numbers concatenated with a letter

Tags: google-sheets, concatenate

I want to concatenate a string after a numerical value in some columns automatically so that way they are still treated as numeric values.

For example:

```
A 
4010H
4011H
4012H
4013H
```

I want to be able to set one number and drag select it and fill in the rest of the column like you normal would with numbers. Ex:Type 4010 and then drag select the others and it fills the numbers 4011-4013.

However I need to keep the **"H"**. The **"H"** breaks the numeric programming of the cells and it just duplicates the first cell.

Like this:

```
4010H
4010H
4010H
4010H
```

My plan was to concatenate the `H`, but how would I do that but keep editability of the numbers?

Is there a way to say current value+"H"?

Answer (score 2):

After entering 4010H in the first row (cell A1), put the formula

```
=split(A1, "H") + 1 & "H"
```

in cell A2, and drag that formula down.

It splits off "H", then adds 1, then puts "H" back again.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to say current value+"H"?

Apply a Custom Number format of:

```
#"H"
```

and behaviour will be the same as with numbers only (including for example, summing), just display an appended `H`.